# Why can't I set the source (from xaml file) of a ResourceDictionary in cross platform project?

Tags: c#, mobile, cross-platform, resourcedictionary

I want to be able to switch from ResourceDictionary (load from file) dynamically in C# code from App.xaml.cs but ResourceDictionary.Source is not a property of the object, why? fyi, this is a cross-platform mobile app and not a WPF project. Here is my "unsatisfying code":

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyCondCP
{

public partial class App : Application
{


    private void SetLanguageDictionary()
    {
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Resources\\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

...
```

I get this error: ResourceDictionary does not contain a definition for "Source" ...

Am I missing an assembly or reference? Anyhow, is there a way for me to load a ResourceDictionary from a file/.xaml instead of having to set key/value resource in code one by one?

I found a sample code on StackOverflow (not working for me): 
[How to change ResourceDictionary Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867091/how-to-change-resourcedictionary-dynamically)

Comment: I have found this but it is internal ResourceDictionary.SetAndLoadSource(Uri, String, Assembly, IXmlLineInfo) Method
Definition
Namespace:
Xamarin.Forms
Assembly:
Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
For internal use by the Xamarin.Forms platform.

C#

Copy
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable]
public void SetAndLoadSource (Uri value, string resourcePath, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo);

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. How can I set the source of a ResourceDictionary from App.xaml.cs in a Cross platform mobile project?